# How to replace the max distance of a bounded set of points with a random point in less than $O(n^2)$?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

## Context

Let's say I have a finite set of points of size $N$.

I can represent the points in a metric space and then compute distances between them.

My goal is to replace a point in the set with another one (let's say a completely random point), only if the new point maximum distance is better than a set's point maximum distance.

For example let's say I have a set of size $N = 6$ points, with the following distances :

|  | $S_1$ | $S_2$ | $S_3$ | $S_4$ | $S_5$ | $S_6$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $S_1$ | 0 | 80 | 30 | 80 | 72 | 41 |
| $S_2$ | 80 | 0 | 85 | 113 | 72 | 41 |
| $S_3$ | 30 | 85 | 0 | 50 | 50 | 45 |
| $S_4$ | 80 | 113 | 50 | 0 | 45 | 81 |
| $S_5$ | 72 | 72 | 50 | 45 | 0 | 50 |
| $S_6$ | 41 | 41 | 45 | 81 | 50 | 0 |

Now I randomly generate a point $S_k$ and compute the distances between it and the set's points :

|  | $S_1$ | $S_2$ | $S_3$ | $S_4$ | $S_5$ | $S_6$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $S_k$ | 54 | 36 | 71 | 112 | 81 | 32 |

The biggest distances in my set are respectively :

|  | $S_1$ | $S_2$ | $S_3$ | $S_4$ | $S_5$ | $S_6$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| max($S_i$) | 80 | 113 | 85 | 113 | 72 | 81 |

Now you can see that max($S_k$) is greater than max($S_1$) and max($S_3$) and max($S_5$) and max($S_6$).

What I want to do is replace the point with the smallest max($S_i$) with $S_k$, if max($S_k$) > max($S_i$).

In that example I can replace $S_5$ by $S_k$ :

|  | $S_1$ | $S_2$ | $S_3$ | $S_4$ | $S_k$ | $S_6$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $S_1$ | 0 | 80 | 30 | 80 | 54 | 41 |
| $S_2$ | 80 | 0 | 85 | 113 | 36 | 41 |
| $S_3$ | 30 | 85 | 0 | 50 | 71 | 45 |
| $S_4$ | 80 | 113 | 50 | 0 | 112 | 81 |
| $S_k$ | 54 | 36 | 71 | 112 | 0 | 32 |
| $S_6$ | 41 | 41 | 45 | 81 | 32 | 0 |

## My approaches

The naive approach to this problem is to compute the max distance between each point every time a new one is generated and to replace the one with the lowest max distance. As you can guess this approach is highly inefficient, $O(N^2)$, I assume.

My intuition leads me to use memoization to solve this problem efficiently. The maximum distance for each point is stored in memory, and updated whenever a point is replaced in the set. However, I have issues with this method :

- The point erased from the set may contain the max distance for another point, thus changing the latter's max distance to something completely new. It means I have to go through the entire column/line for a solution to find its maximum distance again, inducing the worst complexity of $O(N^2)$. In the previous example, if I had to replace $S_2$ with $S_k$, this would happen.
- If I try to get around that by storing the two biggest max distances for each solution, the issue is the same. If the solution erased is the second max distance of another solution, I have to go through the entire column/line again to find the second maximum distance for that solution.

## Questions

Now I have several questions regarding this problem :

- Is it possible that the case of erasing a point from the set leads to erasing the max for other points? I thought about that case but did not encounter it in my examples. Do some triangular inequality property prevents this from happening or can it happen?
- Is memoization a good approach to that problem? If not, what other paradigm could I try to solve efficiently?

Comment: There's a lot written here.  I don't know what "new point maximum distance" or "set's point maximum distance" means.  Please define all special terms, such as "maximum distance" or "set's point".  What do you mean by "randomly generate a point"?  Do you mean to pick a random point from the set?  Or to generate a new point?    Where did your "biggest distances" come from?  What does max($S_i$) mean?